# Stop repeating values Excel 2013 Pivot Table

Tags: excel, pivot-table, powerpivot

I am having a problem getting Pivot Tables (created from a PowerPivot model) presenting repeating data values where I am not expecting data.

To simplify the model, I am attempting to describe it below (since I am unable to post images here):

**Table 1**

- Columns: Org, Org Name
- Row 1: H, Human Resources
- Row 2: S, Sales
- Row 3: M, Marketing
  [image]

**Table 2**

- Columns: Application, Org Name
- Row 1: bizPaycheck, Human Resources
- Row 2: bizLeads, Sales
- Row 3: bizProducts, Marketing

[image]

I took the data into PowerPivot where I then created a Pivot Table based on my data set.

**Selected Fields in Pivot Table**

- Table: 1, Column: Org
- Table: 2, Column: Application

[image]

I'd like to filter on all applications for Org: H. Instead, the Pivot Table presents the data like below:
[image]

- Columns: Application, Org
- Row 1: bizPaycheck, H
- Row 2: bizPaycheck, S
- Row 3: bizPaycheck, M
- Row 4: bizLeads, H
- Row 5: bizLeads, S
- Row 6: bizLeads, M
- Row 7: bizProducts, H
- Row 8: bizProducts, S
- Row 9: bizProducts, M

Can anyone provide perspective into why Excel is assigning values for all Orgs to all Applications?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Repeating values usually indicate that you are trying to relate a fact to a dimension that is unrelated.  I'm finding it hard to picture what you are describing and what your goal is.  Can you post a link to some screenshots?  I (or someone else) can edit your post and add them in for you.

Comment: @mmarie Sure! [Org Table (PPV)](http://oi43.tinypic.com/2jcx553.jpg), [App Table (PPV)](http://oi43.tinypic.com/33jmhd3.jpg), [Relationship Diagram](http://oi42.tinypic.com/2li7axl.jpg), and the [Pivot Table](http://oi40.tinypic.com/10dxs1u.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@nmarie had it identified correctly. There was no relationship to the dimensions I was trying to show. Solved it by creating a flat pivot table and sliced on different dimensions.